# how do I delete some extra text from data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

```
    car_names = soup.find_all("h3")
data =[]
for name in car_names:
    data.append({"Car Name": name.text})

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

I need to delete the "/n" and "for sale" from some entries [image]

Comment: Please check the Solution provided, that should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see you have already a DataFrame structure and a column that is `Car Name`, Just run the below code, and you will get what you are looking for..

### sample DataFrame:

```
>>> df
                     Car Name
0        This car is for sale
1  \nThis car is not for sale
```

### Solution:

Try `replace` and use the `dict` method to carry both the changes at once with `regex=True` else it will not work.

```
>>> df['Car Name'].replace({"for sale": '', "\n": ''}, regex=True)
0        This car is
1    This car is not
Name: Car Name, dtype: object
```

OR

```
>>> df['Car Name'] = df['Car Name'].replace({"for sale": '', "\n": ''}, regex=True)
>>> df
           Car Name
0      This car is
1  This car is not
```

Another way:

```
m = {"for sale": '', "\n": ''}
df['Car Name'].replace(m, regex=True)
0        This car is
1    This car is not
Name: Car Name, dtype: object
```

Comment: @AbdurehmanDar, Glad to see its working, even you can upvote if you like the solution.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
   def delete(text):
           return text.replace('for Sale','').replace('\n','')
    df.urColumnName=df.urColumnName.apply(delete)
```

Comment: probably this is better: `test.strip().replace("for Sale", "")`

Comment: i agree  it would delete extra spaces

Comment: None of them seems to be working I have also added the code kindly have a look.

Answer (score 0):

For strings you can use `str.replace("for Sale", "")`

The first entry is the expression you want to delete, the second one what you want to insert (in your case: nothing).

You just have to iterate through your dataframe and apply this to all the columns you want.

Answer (score 0):

If it is some random entries, and you want to do it manually, it is probably easier to write your dataframe to a csv using `df.to_csv()`, adjust the .csv file manually, and import the csv file back using:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('abc.csv')
```

If it is for all data, use e.g.:

```
df.str.replace("\n","")
```